# Failing to create user with password via Keycloak Rest API

Tags: rest, migration, keycloak, credentials, keycloak-rest-api

I'm trying to migrate users from existing database. Passwords are encrypted with sha512.
I use Keycloak 10 with the REST API.

I have read the [CredentialRepresentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/10.0/rest-api/index.html#_credentialrepresentation)  and y Have try put JSON into the strings for attributes [secretData](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/04415d34eab5ed577c472802df4ca11fbafabc7e/server-spi/src/main/java/org/keycloak/models/credential/dto/PasswordSecretData.java#L10) and [credentialData](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/04415d34eab5ed577c472802df4ca11fbafabc7e/server-spi/src/main/java/org/keycloak/models/credential/dto/PasswordCredentialData.java#L6).

My post user (with correct Authorization) return "error": "unknown_error".

```
POST <someDomain>/auth/admin/realms/assure/users
{
"firstName": "test_encrypte",
"lastName":"test_encrypte", 
"email":"jeremy.rafflin@mail.fr", 
"credentials": [{
    "type":"password",
            "credentialData" : "{\"value\":\"fdVjg7Ed/dck1eSGobCHG4JtObyE3BNE3xZhCuuJ0PpmGB4d/OO+t0C5PwYhtOnUV++X2Jh0xmNdNu+sTkt4Bw==\",\"salt\":\"98cj35ZuYZR7S6N.MvZ2lA/UYfWAztXfF.nm/hFIQso\"}",
    "secretData": "{\"algorithm\":\"sha512\",\"hashIterations\":1}"
}],
"username":"encrypt",
"emailVerified": false,
"enabled": true,
"attributes": {"assureId":"10406440"}
}
```

I using keycloak standalone.

[image: My request]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some issues with your JSON, first instead of :

```
"secretData": "{\"algorithm\":\"sha512\",\"hashIterations\":1}"
```

it is:

```
"credentialData": "{\"algorithm\":\"sha512\",\"hashIterations\":1}"
```

as you can check in the [Keycloak open source repo](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/server-spi/src/main/java/org/keycloak/models/credential/dto/PasswordCredentialData.java).

and instead of

```
"credentialData" : "{\"value\":\"fdVjg7Ed/dck1eSGobCHG4JtObyE3BNE3xZhCuuJ0PpmGB4d/OO+t0C5PwYhtOnUV++X2Jh0xmNdNu+sTkt4Bw==\",\"salt\":\"98cj35ZuYZR7S6N.MvZ2lA/UYfWAztXfF.nm/hFIQso\"}",
```

is actually:

```
"secretData" : "{\"value\":\"fdVjg7Ed/dck1eSGobCHG4JtObyE3BNE3xZhCuuJ0PpmGB4d/OO+t0C5PwYhtOnUV++X2Jh0xmNdNu+sTkt4Bw==\",\"salt\":\"98cj35ZuYZR7S6N.MvZ2lA/UYfWAztXfF.nm/hFIQso\"}",
```

as you can check in the [Keycloak open source repo](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/server-spi/src/main/java/org/keycloak/models/credential/dto/PasswordSecretData.java).

Finally, the salt value has to be base 64 encoded so instead of

```
98cj35ZuYZR7S6N.MvZ2lA/UYfWAztXfF.nm/hFIQso\
```

it has to be:

```
OThjajM1WnVZWlI3UzZOLk12WjJsQS9VWWZXQXp0WGZGLm5tL2hGSVFzbw==
```

The Json that you are looking for is :

```json
{
  "firstName": "test_encrypte",
  "lastName": "test_encrypte",
  "email": "jeremy.rafflin@ageo.fr",
  "credentials": [
    {
      "type": "password",
      "secretData": "{\"value\":\"fdVjg7Ed/dck1eSGobCHG4JtObyE3BNE3xZhCuuJ0PpmGB4d/OO+t0C5PwYhtOnUV++X2Jh0xmNdNu+sTkt4Bw==\",\"salt\":\"OThjajM1WnVZWlI3UzZOLk12WjJsQS9VWWZXQXp0WGZGLm5tL2hGSVFzbw==\"}",
      "credentialData": "{\"algorithm\":\"sha512\",\"hashIterations\":1}"
    }
  ],
  "username": "encrypt",
  "emailVerified": false,
  "enabled": true,
  "attributes": {
    "assureId": "10406440"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For information, I found the problem:
these two lines are not identical :

```
credentialData": "{​​​​​​​\"algorithm\":\"sha512\",\"hashIterations\":1}​​​​​​​"

"credentialData": "{\"algorithm\":\"sha512\",\"hashIterations\":1}"
```

If I compare them with [Character Code Finder](http://www.mauvecloud.net/charsets/CharCodeFinder.html) The decimal codes are differents.
for exemple my } code is "125, 8203, 8203, 8203, 8203, 8203, 8203, 8203" and your is "125".

PS : sorry for my english, I am french.

@dreamcrash : Thank you for you very much for your time

Comment: So it was encoding problem after all I update my answer hopefully with the correct encoding