# Keycloak type=LOGIN_ERROR error=invalid_user_credentials w/ sha512

Tags: php, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I installed a keycloak server ( docker jboss/keycloak ).

I am trying to create a user via the API with a password hashed using salted SHA512.

User password is 1234 ( obviously a terrible password ).

Here is the password hash I have, I generated it using PHP crypt :

```
<?php

var_dump( crypt( '1234', '$6$7ZA1w5u9hBAWnY1f$') );

?>
```

```
$6$7ZA1w5u9hBAWnY1f$JNwIYgxiK7c0umoNz2dLJsheKdLT.fgUuibCAhSvlZBw5pLG1SfjhoZCiQltO94s2uDK4jGsowGQlcRNtdDtS.
```

$6$ means sha512. It's using 5000 iterations.

This is the resulting json for the create user query :

```
    {
    "username": "Alice61c37c2f94cf7",
    "email": "Alice61c37c2f94cfd",
    "firstName": "Alice",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "enabled": true,
    "credentials": [
        {
            "type": "password",
            "credentialData": "{\"hashIterations\":5000,\"algorithm\":\"sha512\"}",
            "secretData": "{\"salt\":\"N1pBMXc1dTloQkFXblkxZg==\",\"value\":\"JNwIYgxiK7c0umoNz2dLJsheKdLT.fgUuibCAhSvlZBw5pLG1SfjhoZCiQltO94s2uDK4jGsowGQlcRNtdDtS.\"}"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try and login to keycloak it says invalid/user password and the keycloak console spits out this :

```
19:29:18,005 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-17) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=master, clientId=security-admin-console, userId=069a112b-6272-4bbe-b04d-eaba5b40b407, ipAddress=192.168.0.14, error=invalid_user_credentials, auth_method=openid-connect, auth_type=code, redirect_uri=http://192.168.0.17:22755/auth/admin/master/console/, code_id=69ba5c79-cc04-43a0-9578-2fd8960701ce, username=Alice61c37c2f94cf7, authSessionParentId=69ba5c79-cc04-43a0-9578-2fd8960701ce, authSessionTabId=Ou1kBZ4lZ6U
```

I saw this related question [Failing to create user with password via Keycloak Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65955189/failing-to-create-user-with-password-via-keycloak-rest-api) and wonder if my salt and value are maybe misencoded. I tried passing salt into base64_encode and passing it directly.

I saw this related question [Migrating user password from sha512 to pbkdf2-sha512 for keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66495314/migrating-user-password-from-sha512-to-pbkdf2-sha512-for-keycloak) but it doesn't seem to be relevant because I am using sha512 and not pbkdf-sha512.